# Is there a fast way of gathering image files from external sources (Chrome Developer Tab)

Tags: download, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say I visit a website named **abc.xyz**.

When I get to the website, I see the website runs a javascript script to create an interactive book. Obviously, the book must have image files for each page.

Now let's say I go to the developer tools tab and go to the sources tab to find the images - sure enough, I find them. However, the images come from a folder and domain named **xyz.abc** that displays a *403* error when accessed.

Is there a faster way of gathering these image files than visiting the links for every single image and individually saving every single image (Bare in mind the images themselves are not restricted access)?

**Real World Example:**
[Image showing files under the sources tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCYBx.png)

In the image above, you can see there are several image files located in a folder (hundreds, in fact). The domain and folder the images reside in display 403 errors when accessed, however the images themselves are not restricted. To download the images, you can individually get the link to each image and use "Save image as". However, this will be time-consuming for hundreds of images - is there a faster way to download all the images?

**Edit**: Furthermore, would there be a way to quickly order PDF images via a pre-existing page number on the PDF file.

Comment: Use an extension or utility to download images, there are many.

Comment: you can create a python script to download all the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get images of a webpage , you can use python script to fetch all the image `src` which later u can perform any operations on it , such as copy it to your system or into your website .**

**I've used `BeautifulSoup` for webscraping**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939080/is-there-a-fast-way-of-gathering-image-files-from-external-sources-chrome-devel")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
for element in soup.find_all("img"):
    try:
        print(element['src'])
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to gather the images (with a bit of modification since the website was a bit weird), but I'll mark this as correct.

Note for future readers: If you get a 403 error, try adding a header.